# Change Android minimum API for project in "project scructure" (android 3.4.2 is super buggy it seems)

Tags: android, api

so after I updated my android recently, I could no longer create a new project nor change API level in "Project scructure" and it seems lots of options are no longer there when it can open, when it cant open it gets an error and I have sent the bug report. Its buggy.

So long story short, is there a way to change the api level by acessing a file in project? some XML file? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried my answer yet OP ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

the minimum sdk version is defined in `build.gradle`, where you can change :

`minSdkVersion 21`

to any version you want